# How do I generate a lexer with the Go toolchain?

Tags: parsing, go, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

A parser is generated with

```
go tool yacc foo.y
```

But there is no `go tool lex` command, so how do I generate a lexer from `foo.l`?

Comment: I recommend: [Lexical Scanning in Go - Rob Pike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxaD_trXwRE) (wherein the short answer is that it's usually easy enough to write your own and you get much better error reporting that way too).

Comment: @DaveC: The funny thing is that I was willing to write my own parser (because parsing Scheme is easy), but wanted a lexer generator because some of the tokens get messy with all the "special" tokens such as character literals and escaped symbols. But I guess I'll take their advice and write everything myself.

Comment: @Matt FWIW a while ago I wrote a lexer using the `text/scanner` package that let me have the basics already there, and I had to add very little to a simple scanning loop in order to be able to "feed my yacc" :).

Comment: @Matt I'd still recommend viewing that video first then as he discusses an interesting (to me at least) way of using channels to structure the code and avoid the typical "NextToken" function of a lexer having to unwind/reset its state each call. The code he talks about was the first version of Go's text/template package https://golang.org/src/text/template/parse/lex.go

Comment: @DaveC: That's how I already started writing it a few years ago anyway. But I'll still watch it because I remember having problems with channels not being closed and such.